# On the existence of certain Weierstrass-type Extreme Value Theorems

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series, reference-request, soft-question

It is well-known that *Weierstrass Extreme Value Theorem* can be generalized to lower and upper semi-continuous functions. Are there any other generalizations of this important result; and more in general,

> is there such a thing as a set of ***Weierstrass-type extreme value
>   theorems***? If yes, where can I find a list (with both *statements* and *proofs*)?